# PHP file downloaded instead open in CPanel Hosting

Tags: php, cpanel

I use Ubuntu 16.x and now I try in macOS Sierra but I still get this problem. I have read all question regarding this problem but most cases are happen in local server.

I have download Apache2, and PHP 5 in my Ubuntu but its not solved my problem. I don't have any Idea to solved this. I have a hosting in CPanel and local (lampp) in my Ubuntu. In local server, .php can be execute but when I the put in my hosting it is downloaded instead execute. Is there specific setting in my CPanel or else?

Comment: If PHP code is presented as a file download, it means PHP is not running on that server or the engine is disabled in that specific directory. There's nothing else to it.

Comment: @icecub how to make it enable? I really don't have any idea about this -.-

Comment: Ask your server provider to enable it. There can be any number of reasons why it isn't enabled. It's impossible for me or anyone else here to know. Your question is the same as "My car is broken. How do I fix it?". No one can answer that without looking at your car first either.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I solved this problem. Maybe there are someone who use CPanel and get same case with me. I remove all setting in `htaccess` and `PHP` can execute instead download. Hope this help. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

you must add php handler in apache config

```
<FilesMatch \.php$>
SetHandler application/x-httpd-php
```

Answer (score 0):

For me, it was due to the PHP version used by my hosting service.
I had to change it to the latest (7.4) and the PHP file started getting executed (not downloaded) on the browser.